# Understanding multi monitor dpi

Tags: windows, winapi, resolution, monitor, multiple-monitors

On Windows 8.1 I created a firefox addon to take a screenshot.

I'm having an issue. This is what I'm doing:

1. I have a setup like this (mon1 is not primary monitor, has res of 1920x1080, monitor 2 is primary and has res of 1280x1024)

   - [image]
2. Screenshot all monitors to ImageData.
3. Open two featureless/borderless windows with this code:
4. Then after window opens I move it to the originX and originY of each monitor then make it fullscreen:

   aEditorDOMWindow.moveTo(colMon[iMon].x, colMon[iMon].y);

   aEditorDOMWindow.focus();
      aEditorDOMWindow.fullScreen = true;
5. Then I create a canvas with width x height matching screen resolution  in each window and draw to it the monitors screenshot

So now the problem is, the windows open on monitor 2, then when i move it to monitor 1 and inspect canvas, the size is 1920x1080 which matches the resolution, but in the video recording below I measured it with photoshop and it visually is actually 2880 x 1620.

Here is a youtube screencast demonstrating it:
[Youtube :: Why other monitor almost double size?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzS3YgXhtLU)

I always notice as I drag a window from one monitor to another it slightly changes size, what is this called? Is it specific to Window8.1+? Is there anyway with WinAPI I can trigger this resize?

Answer (score 3):

You no doubt see the DPI virtualization feature of Windows at work.  Nothing you can do about it in this case, it is up to the main application to declare itself multi-monitor DPI aware.

It doesn't, the subject of [Mozilla bug #890156](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890156).  Two years old already, they are not in a hurry to fix it.  Not a lot of votes, you can add one.

Comment: I don't experience this issue when I create one huge window the size of all monitors combined and position it at the top left most point then draw in the screenshots on the canvas at the proper x y of the monitors: http://imgur.com/qlWmwZo,48fHFxP can you please help me understand why?

Comment: You did not move the window to the 1st monitor before you created the screenshot.  So it wasn't rescaled.

Comment: Wow thanks Hans!! I'm going to try to move the window to 1st monitor then draw and see what happens. Ill report back!

Comment: Hi @HansPassant can you please reword the "move window to 1st mon before created screenshot" I can't seem to get it to work out, I think Im misunderstanding. I create the window at position of the primary monitor (1, 1) and then draw the screenshot to it, then move it to 1st monitor and its still scaled up x1.5 :(

Comment: You do have to take the answer in stride: "nothing you can do about".  DPI virtualization is a feature, not a bug.  Without it the pixels are too close together so the window is too small.  It prevents a window from turning into a postage stamp that you can't read unless you press your nose against the screen.  The cure is to make the window bigger, Firefox will not do this for you.  Did you vote yet?

Comment: Ah forgive that I just thought because I could get the single window expanding across all to work (not rescale) i thought i could get multi to work as well. I voted already thanks so much for finding that bug.

Comment: Oh my goodness @Hans this is soooooo weird, if I make the window size so its big enough to reach the primary its not rescaling it, this is soooo mind boggling. Would you be able to chat ideally would you be able to chat over a WebEx or something similiar so I can show you this super psychadellic behavior please?

Comment: Actually forgive that I know thats an awkward requesting to connect to each others computers of strangers. Is it possible though on your end if you can figure out what is happening under the hood? By having the window of non-primary monitor resized such that it covers at least 50% of the primary monitor its preventing rescale. I was hoping to execute whats happening under the hood without resizing to prevnt the rescale. Please forgive me I know you said theres nothing we can do but there seems there is, if you could please forgive my persistance and and please help that would be soooo awesome!

Comment: Thanks for linking that bug and making me vote, we got the attention of the big dogs :) Jim Mathies acted on it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890156#c29